# Return the divisors of n using the filter function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> Create a divisors :: Int -> [Int] function that returns the divisors
> of x.

I've successfully made a `divides` function that returns `True` if `y` is a divisor of `x`.

```
divides x y | mod x y == 0 = True
            | mod x y /= 0 = False
```

I've tried to use it to filter numbers from `[1..n]` , but can't exactly get a grasp on how the filter function works. Can anyone set me in the right direction?

```
divisors n = filter divides n [1..n]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right track. Only that your problem is not exactly how filter works, but how Haskell works.

```
divisors n = filter (divides n) [1..n]
```

The above will do the trick. See, filter takes two arguments, so does divisors. But you are giving it three arguments at `filter divides n [1..n]`.

Btw,

```
divides x y | mod x y == 0 = True
            | mod x y /= 0 = False
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
divides x y = mod x y == 0
```

and operationally it doesn't repeat the mod calculation and the test `mod x y /= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` takes as its second argument a list to filter - here your `[1..n]` - and as first argument a function which takes one of those list elements as input and returns a boolean.

So think about what this function would be, in terms of your pre-defined function `divides`. Since, as you have it, `divides x y` actually means "`y` is a divisor of `x`", you can easily express this with a lambda function:

```
divisors n = filter (\m -> divides n m) [1..n]
```

which can be further simplified by "eta-reduction" (or coloquially, "cancelling the `m`") to

```
divisors n = filter (divides n) [1..n]
```